# Is it still possible to start and finish a quest from Chapter 1 after starting Chapter 2?

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

*Baldur's Gate: Enhanced Edition* is divided by chapter. When I start Chapter 2, will I still be able to activate quests from Chapter 1? In my journal, all previous chapter quests disappeared after starting Chapter 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a new Chapter does not prevent you completing quests you started previously.

In this specific case however, you won't be able to re-enter Candlekeep to do the quests.

Comment: IIRC the Candlekeep part is labeled as Prologue and is more of a tutorial than a real chapter, but it is separate from the next chapters.